# Enter before continue

Tags: scripts

I make some scripts to install programs automatic but is there a option to do the following.

Press Enter to continue or any other key to skip and go to the next thing? For example, the script will install keylock indicator and touchpad indicator but you want only the touchpad indicator.

Comment: Something like this [How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script) ?

Comment: Yes, but that gives also a exit. That is what I not want.

Comment: You can substitute `exit` with `break` if you don't want to leave the script completely.

Comment: This is really too broad to answer. Please include your actual script, the details will depend on what exactly you are doing. The classic approach is to prompt for user input using `read` and then use a `case` or `if/else` statement to react to whatever the user chose.

Comment: I don't have a script now to show, but I want it for later. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nicely resolve this problem using a menu with select-case statement. A working example can be found here:

[How can I create a select menu in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: @Korkel if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: I did? Was not saved?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using shell script?

```
read -p "Install XX? [yN] " -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    # do install
fi
```