# bash script which checks input to see if it is "y", "n" or other - not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have written this bash script which is meant to check your input to see if it is `y`, `n` or something else (this will be part of a larger project):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Have you updated the PATH variable in your .bashrc file yet? [y/n]"
read response

        if [$response = "y"]; then
                echo "Checkpoint passed"
                set $checkpoint = "t"
        elif [$response = "n"]; then
                echo "Please set the PATH variable in your .bashrc file before running this script."
                set $checkpoint = "f"
        else            
                echo "Please only use 'y' and 'n'."
                set $checkpoint = "f"
        fi
```

But every time that I run it I get an error similar to this one no matter what I put in:

```
Have you updated the PATH variable in your .bashrc file yet? [y/n]
y
./snbjdkhome: line 6: [y: command not found
./snbjdkhome: line 9: [y: command not found
Please only use 'y' and 'n'.
```

So what is wrong with my code? (I am very new to shell scripting.)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bbar.3D.22.24foo.22.5D.3B_then_... also, if you're building menus, use `case` (preferably with [`select`](http://askubuntu.com/q/1705/158442)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will make you clear (Check the Whitespaces):

```
$ var=c

$ ["$var" == "c"] && echo "OK"
[c: command not found

$ ["$var" == "c" ] && echo "OK"
[c: command not found

$ [ "$var" == "c"] && echo "OK"
bash: [: missing `]'

$ [ "$var" == "c" ] && echo "OK"
OK
```

So, you need to put whitespace prior to and after the condition while using `test` (`[ ]`)command.

Answer (score 4):

there is one simple error on line 6 and 9. There should be space between `[` and `$response` in `if [$response = "y"]then` on line 6; . Similarly, for `[` and `$response` on line 9`

Also you must put double qoutes around `$response` to avoid errors in case user enters a input with space.

Answer (score 3):

Also, the `set` command is more exotic than you think. 
You don’t use the `set` command to set variables.

You know that, when you invoke a shell script with parameters,
that they get assigned to `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, …; right?  Well,
*one* of the things the `set` command does is to set `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, …
for the *current* (interactive) shell.  So, for example,

```bsh
% set checkpoint="y"
% echo "$checkpoint"
                                (nothing)
% echo "arg1 = '$1', arg2 = '$2', arg3 = '$3'"
arg1 = 'checkpoint=y', arg2 = '', arg3 = ''
% set checkpoint = "y"
% echo "$checkpoint"
                                (nothing)
% echo "arg1 = '$1', arg2 = '$2', arg3 = '$3'"
arg1 = 'checkpoint', arg2 = '=', arg3 = 'y'
```

which is not what you want.

And you have another problem.  The correct syntax is

```bsh
checkpoint="t"
```

If you say

```bsh
$checkpoint="t"
```

and `$checkpoint` is not set, this command reduces to

```bsh
="t"
```

which looks for a program called `=t` (which probably doesn’t exist).  Similarly,

```bsh
$checkpoint = "t"
```

reduces to

```bsh
= "t"
```

which looks for a program called `=`. 
Even worse, if `$checkpoint` is already set to `"t"`, and you say

```bsh
$checkpoint="f"
```

then that is interpreted as

```bsh
t="f"
```

thus setting the variable `t` (i.e., `$t`).

Answer (score 1):

Bash interprets your `$response`  as commands it can't find. Enclose them in double-quotes like the strings you compare them to, and it should work as expected.