# Best directory to place my bash scripts?

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm developing some scripts. One for the [annoying speaker beep regression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829258/turn-off-motherboard-pc-speaker-beep-in-ubuntu-16-04-regression) that popped in Ubuntu 16.04 even though `pcspkr` is blacklisted. Another to fix a [PulseAudio 8.0 bug in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840473/ubuntu-changing-default-audio-output-after-suspend/840543#840543) where sound switches off from TV to the laptop.

What is the best directory to put my bash scripts in?

I've searched the Q&A database but I get a bunch of different answers for a bunch of different scenarios.

`/usr/local` has been recommended by one person because it's in the PATH$. Is that the right thing to do?

Thank you for your advice.

---

Even though I accepted below answer over a year ago, I ended up using:

- `/usr/local/bin` for scripts needing sudo powers
- `/home/me/bin` for scripts running at user level

After creating directory `/home/me/bin` you need to log out and in again for it to get into your PATH.