# Beeping sound when plugging charger

Tags: 14.04, sound, battery

My cousin installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my grandmother's new notebook, but every time I unplug or plug the charger the system emits a loud beep. The volume setting doesn't matter, but when an earphone is connected, the beep goes through it.

Can somebody pinpoint the problem, or tell me if it's even related to the OS configuration? It doesn't really change anything, but it's getting really annoying.

### Hardware

Acer Aspire One 722

Processor AMD Dual-Core C-50 (1.0 GHz) 64-bit

Gallium 0.4 on AMD PALM (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

Comment: Please describe your hardware.

Comment: Is there a BIOS option for sound on charger connection, or to enable/disable the 
system beep?

Comment: I wish my laptop beeped if the charger was accidentally unplugged. It's plugged in 24/7 and if it accidentally wiggled loose the beep would be handy. Why are you plugging it in and unplugging the charger all the time to annoy yourself? If you want to know about annoying beeps with keystrokes read this: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/829258/turn-off-motherboard-pc-speaker-beep-in-ubuntu-16-04-regression)

Comment: Nick Weinberg: there isn't, already checked.
WinEunuuchs2Unix: I don't do it all the time, lol. It's my grandma's computer, and she doesn't like to leave it always charging. But we live in an apartment building, and the neighbors may be annoyed.