# Constant hardware beeping is driving me insane

Tags: sound, xubuntu

I got myself an acer TravelMate B117 a while ago and it was running fine with linux. But after a while there was a reoccuring beep noise that doesn't come from the speakers.Sometimes theres no beep for hours and sometimes it doesn't seem to stop.It always comes in bursts of 3 except sometimes the last ones.It beeps a total of 1 to sometimes 15 times or even more and i can't seem to find the reason for it let alone stop it. I already checked my logs and couldn't fine anything extraordinary, same with dmesg.It occures too under linux mint and xubuntu.I already sent the laptop to acer where it got its system reset and the mainboard changed but that didn't help.The strange thing is that everything is running fine except for the beeps adn i get no error messages while it beeps.So if one of you has a clue how to resolve this issue i would be very thankful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off Motherboard/PC Speaker "beep" in Ubuntu 16.04 regression](http://askubuntu.com/questions/829258/turn-off-motherboard-pc-speaker-beep-in-ubuntu-16-04-regression)

Comment: No the beep comes for no reason at all even when the laptop is just sitting there and i dont want to change the sound but eliminate it.

Comment: Does it beep if you take out the battery?

Comment: Didn't try that yet do you mean the CMOS battery or the power supply?

Comment: The power supply. Some batteries have built-in warnings that they are end-of-life. This may result in a beep, or a blinking led.

Comment: Will try that but the beep occurs also when the laptop is fully charged and attached to the DC adapter