# How can I display a reminder while or before shutdown?

Tags: shutdown

My computer speakers make a horrible sound while shutting down and I keep forgetting to turn them off before shutdown. I would like to prevent this with a "just in time" reminder. Something like a popup window that also delays shut down until I click a confirmation button would be great.

Comment: Standard Ubuntu and most of the derivatives with other DEs already do that by default.

Comment: By "horrible sound" do you mean PC Speaker Beep? If so this might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829258/turn-off-motherboard-pc-speaker-beep-in-ubuntu-16-04-regression

Answer (score 1):

To display a message before halting, just follow these steps:

1. Write a script containing the commands you want to be executed, e. g.:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   # for zenity it might be necessary to set the DISPLAY variable first with the following line:
   # DISPLAY=":0.0"
   zenity --warning
   ```
2. save the script wherever you want, I use `~/scripts/myscript` as an example here
3. make it executable with

   ```bsh
   sudo chmod +x ~/scripts/myscript
   ```
4. link it to the shutdown directory using

   ```bsh
   sudo ln -s ~/scripts/myscript /etc/rc0.d/k01zenitywarning
   ```

The script will be executed the next time you shut down. To execute it alsoon reboot, additionally link it to `/etc/rc6.d/` with `sudo ln -s ~/scripts/myscript /etc/rc6.d/k01zenitywarning`.

This does what you asked for, however I also really like *omid abc*'s approach to solve the problem – instead of manually turn off the speakers every time just mute the sound using his command (replace the `zenity` line in the script for that).

#### Edit – simpler approach

An even simpler way is provided by the `upstart` package, after installing it just save the following script in `~/.init/onshutdown.conf`

```bsh
start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=0
task
script
 # for zenity it might be necessary to set the DISPLAY variable first with the following line:
 # DISPLAY=":0.0"
 zenity --warning
end script
```

Again, `zenity --warning` can be replaced by any command(s). This script doesn't need to be made executable, just save it and you're done. For more information about `upstart` see [man 5 init](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/init.5.html).

Comment: I think you need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable if you want to use Zenity from an `rc.*` script.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your problem is to mute volume before shut down.
Write this script in `/etc/rc0.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash    
amixer set Master mute
```

be sure to make this script executable by using `sudo chmod +x myscript`

Note that the script is directory will be executed in alphabetical order.the name of your script must begin with `k99` to run at a right time

By using this solution when you shoutdown your system it will automatically mute volume