# How to disable alert sound for terminal only?

Tags: 16.04, sound

I am really annoyed by the alert sound in terminal when i click backspace and as soon as no character is left in terminal and again i press backspace, it notifies with a sound which i want to disable because i use earphone and is really irritating.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829258/turn-off-motherboard-pc-speaker-beep-in-ubuntu-16-04-regression