# Can line draw characters (or colors) be added to a Bash file list menu?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, menu

I created the world's ugliest menu using the first Linux tool I'm learning, BASH.

### What the Menu Looks Like

```
The following /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds were found
1) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/Amsterdam.ogg
2) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/bell.ogg
3) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/Blip.ogg
4) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/default.ogg
5) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/Mallet.ogg
6) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/message.ogg
7) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/Positive.ogg
8) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/Rhodes.ogg
9) /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/Slick.ogg
'a' to hear to all files, use number to hear a single file, 
'u' to update last single file heard as new default, or 'q' to quit:
```

### The Code

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# NAME: bell-select-menu
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Present menu of bell sounds to listen to all, listen to one and update default.
# CALL: bell-select-menu
# DATE: Created Oct 1, 2016.

echo "The following /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds were found"

# set the prompt used by select, replacing "#?"
PS3="'a' to hear to all files, use number to hear a single file, 
'u' to update last single file heard as new default, or 'q' to quit: "

lastfile="none"

# allow the user to choose a file
select filename in /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/*.ogg

do

    # leave the loop if the user types 'q'
    if [[ "$REPLY" == q ]]; then break; fi

    # play all if the user types 'a'
    if [[ "$REPLY" == a ]] 
    then 
        playall-bells
        continue
    fi

    # update last file name as new default if the user types 'u'
    if [[ "$REPLY" == u ]]
    then
        if [[ "$lastfile" == none ]]
        then
            echo "No file was selected."
            break
        fi
        echo "$lastfile selected"
        cp $lastfile /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/default.ogg
        load-default-bell
        break
    fi

    # complain if no file was selected, and loop to ask again
    if [[ "$filename" == "" ]]
    then
        echo "'$REPLY' is not a valid number"
        continue
    else
        lastfile="$filename"
    fi

    # listen to the selected file
    ogg123 "$filename"

    # loop back to ask for another
    continue
done
```

I based the code on an answer from AskUbuntu: [Create bash menu based on file list (map files to numbers)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682095/create-bash-menu-based-on-file-list-map-files-to-numbers/682146#682146). The menu scrolls off the screen as user options are repeatedly entered though, so the loop needs to be adjusted.

The world's ugliest menu is automatically generated so I can't hard code ASCII line draw characters on the left and right sides. Would I need to call a program to reformat the menu?

The bulk of the menu is generated by a single bash command:

```
select filename in /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/*.ogg
```

I read the Bash manual on the `select` statement but don't see any options. Is there a program that can be called to massage the screen?

The closest thing I've found is called `tput` described here: [linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php) but I'm not sure if it's practical for this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

PS This menu is one of the tools to get rid of annoying loud speaker beep  in Terminal and `gedit` as described here: [Turn off Motherboard/PC Speaker "beep" in Ubuntu 16.04 regression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829258/turn-off-motherboard-pc-speaker-beep-in-ubuntu-16-04-regression)

---

### Edit - Incorporating Accepted Answer

Many thanks to wjandrea for posting code to clean up the menu. Prior to the accepted answer I had added code for color in `echo` strings and PS3 (prompt). I had also put in a loop to redraw the menu to prevent it scrolling off the screen. I also put in a `reset` to clear the screen before repainting. This prevents more and old copy (sometimes truncated) and new copy of the menu appearing at the same time.

### New Menu Look

The colors aren't accurately represented when copying from terminal text output and pasting into AskUbuntu.

```
=====  Sound Files for Bell in /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/  ====

1) Amsterdam.ogg  4) default.ogg    7) Positive.ogg
2) bell.ogg       5) Mallet.ogg     8) Rhodes.ogg
3) Blip.ogg       6) message.ogg    9) Slick.ogg

===========================  Options  ==========================

'a' to hear to all files, use number to hear a single file, 
'u' update last number heard as new bell default, 'q' to quit:
```

This is all that appears on the screen now. There is no `$ sudo bell-menu` call statement visible. No other history of previous commands typed visible.

A screen shot shows the colors accurately and you can see the screen has been programmatically blanked out:

[image: bell-menu]

### New Menu Code

```
#! /bin/bash

# NAME: bell-menu
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Present menu of bell sounds to listen to all, listen to one and update default.
# CALL: sudo bell-menu
# DATE: Created Oct 6, 2016.

# set the prompt used by select, replacing "#?"
PS3="
===========================  Options  ==========================

$(tput setaf 2)'$(tput setaf 7)a$(tput setaf 2)' to hear to all files, use $(tput setaf 7)number$(tput setaf 2) to hear a single file, 
'$(tput setaf 7)u$(tput setaf 2)' update last number heard as new bell default, '$(tput setaf 7)q$(tput setaf 2)' to quit: $(tput setaf 7)"

cd /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/

# Prepare variables for loops
lastfile="none"
wend="n"

while true; do

  tput reset # Clear screen so multiple menu calls can't be seen.

  echo
  echo -e "===== \e[46m Sound Files for Bell in /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/ \e[0m ===="
  echo

  # allow the user to choose a file
  select soundfile in *.ogg; do

    case "$REPLY" in
        q) # leave the loop if the user types 'q'
            wend="y" # end while loop
            break    # end do loop
            ;;
        a) # play all if the user types 'a'
            playall-bells
            break    # end do loop
            ;;
        u) # update last file name as new default if the user types 'u'
            if [[ "$lastfile" == none ]]; then
                echo "No file has been heard to update default. Listen first!"
                continue  # do loop repeat
            fi
            echo "$lastfile selected"
            cp "$lastfile" default.ogg
            load-default-bell
            wend="y" # end while loop
            break    # end do loop
            ;;
    esac

    # complain if no file was selected, and loop to ask again
    if [[ "$soundfile" == "" ]]; then
        echo "$REPLY: not a valid selection."
        continue    # repeat do loop
    else
        lastfile="$soundfile"
    fi

    # listen to the selected file
    canberra-gtk-play --file="$soundfile"

    # loop back to ask for another
    break
  done
  if [[ "$wend" == "y" ]]; then break; fi

done
```

The menu was renamed from `bell-select-menu` to `bell-menu`. Because it resides in `/usr/local/bin` it needs to be called with `sudo bell-menu` and the comments were updated to reflect this fact.

With a little work the **world's ugliest menu** and now become and acceptable looking (but not beautiful) menu.

Comment: What's the goal here? Do you want to add colours and a border, or just make it easier to read? If it's the latter, you could list the basenames of the files instead of listing their full paths.

Comment: I didn't list the full paths, it's built into the bash command isn't it? But yes the overall goal is to make it eye-pleasing / user-friendly.

Comment: If I change directory to `/usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/` before calling `bell-select-menu` the `select filename` bash command still puts in the directory prefix. It would be nice to take it out directory prefix and insert spaces in front of menu numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. The most important thing I changed is that the script moves to the directory before listing the files, and it lists them as their relative path instead of their absolute path.

Also, I made `$PS3` much smaller; used `canberra-gtk-play` because it's preinstalled, where `ogg123` isn't; and used a `case` statement instead of multiple `if` statements.

I couldn't test it because I'm running 14.04.

```
#! /bin/bash

# NAME: bell-select-menu
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Present menu of bell sounds to listen to all, listen to one and update default.
# CALL: bell-select-menu
# DATE: Created Oct 1, 2016.

# set the prompt used by `select`, replacing "#?"
PS3=": "

echo "Options:
a) Play all 
u) Set the last file played as the new default
q) Quit
The following sounds were found in /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/:"

cd /usr/local/bin/bell/sounds/

# Prepare var for the loop.
lastfile="none"

# allow the user to choose a file
select soundfile in *.ogg; do

    case "$REPLY" in
        q) # leave the loop if the user types 'q'
            break
            ;;
        a) # play all if the user types 'a'
            playall-bells
            continue
            ;;
        u) # update last file name as new default if the user types 'u'
            if [[ "$lastfile" == none ]]; then
                echo "No file was selected."
                break
            fi
            echo "$lastfile selected"
            cp "$lastfile" default.ogg
            load-default-bell
            break
            ;;
    esac

    # complain if no file was selected, and loop to ask again
    if [[ "$soundfile" == "" ]]; then
        echo "$REPLY: not a valid selection."
        continue
    else
        lastfile="$soundfile"
    fi

    # listen to the selected file
    canberra-gtk-play --file="$soundfile"

    # loop back to ask for another
    continue
done
```

Comment: Works great! I'm going to add a little color. I like the fact `canberra-gtk-play` doesn't scroll the screen like `ogg123` does. I was wrong thinking **ogg123** was a built in command, I guess I forgot installing it somewhere along the line. I need to update my other scripts to use **canbera** as well.