# List of file types and default Ubuntu applications to open with

Tags: bash, files, default-programs, mime-type, yad

I'm writing a humble file manager and am seeking a list of different file types and what default applications Ubuntu uses to open them with.

So far I've only figured out "text" open with `gedit`, "image" open with `eog` (eye-of-gnome) and "audio" open with `ogg123`. I'm not sure if `ogg123` is a default application though.

I'd appreciate a little help expanding the list in the code below:

```bash
function OpenFileWithMagic () {

local FileType
FileType=$(file -i "$DfName/$2" | grep -oP '(?<=: ).*?(?=/)')
logger "bafman - OpenFileWithMagic - FileType: $FileType DfName: - $DfName parm 1: $1 2: $2 3: $3 4: $4"

case $FileType in

text)
    # TODO: expand list of file types and associated applications to open them with
    if [[ $4 == root ]]; then
        gsu gedit $DfName/$2
    else
        gedit $DfName/$2
    fi ;;
image)
    eog $DfName/$2 ;;
audio)
    ogg123 $DfName/$2 ;;
esac

} ### OpenFileWithMagic ()
export -f OpenFileWithMagic
```

**Notes:** `export` is only required because file is opened when double-clicking from `yad` dialog box. I also need help figuring out "magic" numbers and how one might interpret them. Perhaps an educating link?

---

**Edit** This is not a duplicate of [How to open file with default application from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15354/how-to-open-file-with-default-application-from-command-line) because:

- That question is how to open a file from the **command line**. This question is how do it from a **bash script** within a `case` structure.
- The answer there would result in `rhythembox` being used for sound files which is not wanted. `ogg123` is more suited for playing sounds without a new window being opened and closing with python error messages.
- The answer there would use `xdg-open /bin/mv` resulting in:

  ```
  gvfs-open: /bin/mv: error opening location: No application is registered as handling this file
  ```
- With the above bash script the `file -i /bin/mv` command results in:

  ```
  /bin/mv: application/x-executable; charset=binary
  ```

After filtering out processing for all desired file types within the bash script then the left overs could be passed to `xdg-open` which is used in the duplicate candidate.

---

**Reply to comments** As pointed out by [DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose) major file types can be found in `/usr/share/mime/types`. Here there are additional types to be considered such as `Video` (a suitable default Ubuntu video player needs to be sourced), `Application` (rather than running it, info about the application needs to be displayed) and `Message` (I have no clue how to display this). Additional mime types needing further research are `inode`, `model`, `multipart` and `x-content`.

[rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) pointed out `ogg123` is not a default sound file player in Ubuntu. A suitable installed-by-default  Ubuntu application to play sound files is `canberra-gtk-play` as answered October 5, 2016 by [wjzndrea](https://askubuntu.com/users/301745/wjandrea) in this Q&A: [Can line draw characters (or colors) be added to a Bash file list menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832766/can-line-draw-characters-or-colors-be-added-to-a-bash-file-list-menu).

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of `/usr/share/mime`? For example, there's `/usr/share/mime/types`.

Comment: @DKBose No I've never heard of it but I'll certainly check it out. Thank you.

Comment: "I'm not sure if ogg123 is a default application though." Nope.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks. Someone mentioned the default one on another Q&A I asked last year. I'll have to dig it up.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/270345): You want to open files with the default program, and you think the way to solve it is by some silly bash script parsing the output of some command.

Comment: The goal isn't to rewrite Nautilus using bash. The goal is to tag files across multiple directories and save the tags for future processing. Scaled down Nautilus functionality for identifying files is provided but not full blown running of all applications. Yes performance in bash is slower than C but it allows Rapid Application Development and Prototyping. It can be rewritten in C next year if greater speed  or > 20,000 directories is necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most modern desktop programs don't use `file` but the [Shared MIME-info Database](https://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/latest/) for file types and the [MIME applications associations specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/latest/) for the default applications.

In Bash you can use [xdg-mime](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdg-mime.1.html) to guess the MIME type of a file and to get the default application for a given MIME type:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype bla.sh
application/x-shellscript
$ xdg-mime query default application/x-shellscript
emacs.desktop
```

With [xdg-open](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html) you can just open a file with the default application so you don't actually need to care about MIME types yourself:

```
$ xdg-open bla.sh
```

Comment: +1 for now but I need some time to check it out before accepting. I hope you understand.

Comment: This answer is useful to change program design. Display file names with file type using `xdg-mime query filetype` beside it. Next put `xdg-mime query default` beside that. When double clicking file name use the existing file type instead of calling `file -i` as the current code uses. Answer accepted.