# Can anyone help to create such menu?

Tags: bash, menu

The script should offer a menu with the following options:

● To create a backup copy of a script file.

- The name of the backup copy should have backup after the name of the script and be date stamped e.g. Ass3Script_backup_10_11_2015.
- It should be saved to your home directory using the Environment Variable for your home directory.
- The script should error check that the file exists and is a normal file. If this is not the case then the script should allow the user to re-enter the filename until a valid filename is entered

● To create a date stamped log file called e.g. log_file_10_11_2015 containing:

- A list of who is logged into the system,
- The disk usage and
- Your currently running processes.
- The file should be saved to an existing directory called log_dir which should be situated off your home directory

● To create a copy of a file.

- The file should be in your current directory (the name of the file to be given by the user)
- The destination directory name to be given by the user.
- The script should error check that the file exists and is a normal file.  If this is not the case then the script should allow the user to re-enter the filename until a valid filename is entered.
- The script should check that the destination directory exists.  If this is not the case then the script should allow the user to re-enter the destination directory until a valid directory is entered.

● To move the location of a file in your current directory (the name and destination to be given by the user)

- The script should error check that the file exists and is a normal file.  If this is not the case then the script should allow the user to re-enter the filename until a valid filename is entered.
- The script should check that the destination directory exists.  If this is not the case then the script should allow the user to re-enter the destination directory until a valid directory is entered.

● This script should loop continuously until the user chooses to quit.

Comment: This reads like a homework assignment. Is this such an assignment?

Comment: The basic structure you want is covered in [How can I create a select menu in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script) - the rest of your question is too broad IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the whole answer but, parts you need come from this answer:

- [Backup Linux configuration, scripts and documents to Gmail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493)

#### Bash script (updated) snippet:

```
# Running under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Ubuntu)?
if cat /proc/version | grep Microsoft; then
    Distro="WSL"
else
    Distro="Ubuntu"
fi

today=$( date +%Y-%m-%d-%A )
/mnt/e/bin/daily-backup.sh Daily-$(hostname)-$Distro-backup-$today
```

The file name generated by above code is:

```
Daily-alien-Ubuntu-16.04-Backup-2018-11-29-Thursday.tar.gz.64
```

Where:

- `$(hostname)` produces `alien` (for an AW17R3 in case you are wondering).
- `$Distro` produces `Ubuntu` (when not running under Windows 10).
- `$(lsb_release -sr)` produces `16.04`
- `$Today` produces `2018-11-29-Thursday` (Today's date)

You can find sample code for most of what you need to do all over this website and our sister website called Unix & Linux. There is a proliferate amount of code all over the internet as well.

It is best to just start writing your script and then when you run into problems with a specific line of code post a question on it. I would budget a week for you to get it done (just a wild guess-timate).